# Connecting microservices with APIs

Tags: javascript, rest, microservices

I am very new to the concept of both microservices and APIs. My only coding experience has been simple programs in a variety of languages. I am trying to understand microservices and REST APIs. I have done a lot of searching, but  can't seem to find a clear example of how to connect microservices with APIs to send and receive information between them. Can anybody at least lead me in the right direction? I know there are problem a ton of ways and different for every language, so here an example below.

For example, pretend I have a simple JavaScript program with HTML and CSS for a simple UI. Let's assume I also have a separate JavaScript program with no UI and all it does it calculate some numbers. How would I use an API to GET/POST two numbers to the calculator "microservice" and after calculating, that "microservice" would GET/POST that result back to the UI "microservice"? Can I test this as just two javascript files locally on my laptop by just using localhost for the URL in the API/HTTP Request?

NOTE: I put microservice in quotes because I realize that this is an extremely simplified example of a microservice. I also understand that my question doesn't contain any code or anything, so I apologize for that. I have researched for hours and can't seem to understand how to go about this. I really appreciate anybody's help!

Comment: Google the terms backend frontend rest APIs , connecting backend with frontend, backend frameworks

Answer (score 0):

This is super broad, and there are a lot of options.

The simplest approach is that the JS UI just hits the frontend API as needed (either on some event or via polling), and so when a new calculation request comes in and is answered, the new calculation is logged (to some form of persistence, e.g. a database or message queue) and so the current 'state' of that model changes and the next time the client asks for the current state, it gets that update.

A more complex approach is to set up some form of messaging infrastructure (e.g. pub/sub), and perhaps a websocket connection between the client and the frontend server(s).  Then the event happening on the frontend microservice would be pushed to the client w/o the client asking for it directly.  In that case, you need to account for dropped connections and so on, so that if a client misses an update b/c they're offline they can get the one(s) they missed once they reconnect.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So, I think the first approach is more what I'm looking for. But let's say that I click a button on the UI to calculate two numbers. In that button click function, I want to use an API to send the two numbers to the other javascript microservice to calculate those two numbers and then return the result through an API. I guess I'm more confused on how to actually write the code to make it happen. Not asking you to write out a bunch of code, but do you know of any examples that show something similar to this? Or any more advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a simple microservice I built in JavaScript and Express.js, that works with HTTP requests.

https://github.com/Alisa1989/string-microservice